# c++ NULL terminated array segfault

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a program that splits graphs, I got a class
Graph and an Algorithm class. I compute the partitioning in my Algorithm class and split the graph with a method in the Graph class according to the partitioning.

My code looks like this:
In my GraphClass:

```
void bisectGraph(int *iPartitioning, Graph **Subgraphs, Edge **Separator){
...
    // Store separators in an array
Separator = new Edge*[Separators.size()+1]; //Separators is a vector containing the separating edges
if(Separator == NULL)
    writeErrorMsg("Error assigning memory.", "Graph::bisectGraph");
for(i=0, SepIter = Separators.begin(); SepIter != Separators.end(); i++, SepIter++)
    Separator[i] = *SepIter;
Separator[Separators.size()] = NULL;

}
```

In my Algorithm clas I call it like this:

```
Edge** separators;
Graph** subgraphs;
int somePartitioning;

g->bisectGraph(somePartitioning, subgraphs, separators);
```

Works fine so far, but when I want to work on my separators array like this for instance:

```
for(int i=0; separators[i]!=NULL, i++){
    ...
}
```

I always get a segmentation fault. ddd tells me that at the end of bisectGraph separators contains some content. Since I can't find any other mistake I think i got some concept wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting Separators from? Is it a global variable outside?

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere else. Could you put more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new value of `Separator` is not being propagated to the `separators` variable outside the function call.  Even though it has type `Edge **` you're assigning to it inside the function, but that only assigns to the function's copy of the variable.  Remember that C++ is pass-by-value unless otherwise specified.

You could change the signature to `Edge **&`, but it'd be more sensible to use a vector, and take a parameter of type `vector<Edge *> &`.

Comment: Actually C++ is *always* pass-by-value; it's just that you can pass a reference or a pointer (by value), which allows to dereference the variable pointed to / referenced. ;-)